# How to load the .NET runtime as a node.js module?

Tags: node.js, .net

I'm using the latest `node.js` for Windows x86.
I tried to use the [node-sharp](https://github.com/anodejs/node-sharp) package from github.
It does compile, but when I load it into the node.js process (via `require('./Sharp')`),
The rather strange error: `Error: no error`, cannot load the module `C:\path\to\module\Sharp.node` occurs. 
Has anyone also tried to use this library?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a better alternative is [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge), it is more stable and works now both on Linux and Windows